# What is the difference between "neglect" and "negligence"?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *neglect* and *negligence*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I'd interpret neglect as "willful negligence". Meaning negligence can be unintended, but neglect is an active decision to ignore something. This is a somewhat subjective interpretation though.

For the most part, they are synonymous. However, especially in legal terms, there is a difference in definition.

[Source example](https://languagetips.wordpress.com/2010/01/07/language-tips-neglect-or-negligence-burnt-or-burned/)

> When used in legal terms, according to Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of Law, neglect means ‘a disregard of duty resulting from carelessness, indifference, or willfulness; especially : a failure to provide a child under one’s care with proper food, clothing, shelter, supervision, medical care, or emotional stability.’
>
> According to the same dictionary, negligence, when used in a legal sense means ‘failure to exercise the degree of care expected of a person of ordinary prudence in like circumstances in protecting others from a foreseeable and unreasonable risk of harm in a particular situation.’ it often refers to neglect of a building. So when it comes to legal terms, neglect is usually used in reference to people, and negligence is usually used in reference to things.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are talking about the noun [neglect](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neglect) :

> - The act of neglecting.
> - The state of being neglected.
> - Habitual lack of care.

and [negligence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/negligence) :

> - The state of being negligent.
> - (law, singular only) The tort whereby a duty of reasonable care was breached, causing damage: any conduct short of intentional or reckless action that falls below the legal standard for preventing unreasonable injury.
> - (law, uncountable) The breach of a duty of care: the failure to exercise a standard of care that a reasonable person would have in a similar situation.

So, it looks like they are **synonyms**.

Etymologically, *"negligence"* comes from old french while *"neglect"* comes directly from latin, and might be considered as purer.

However, they are both principally used in **law** where *"[negligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligence)"* is an **area of tort law** while *"[neglect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neglect)"* is a **passive form of abuse**.